# How to write this MySQL join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database, join

I need to write a MySQL join query for the following scenario.

- I have a answers table which has id, score, student_id, tests_passed, created_at, problem_id.
- I have a problem table, which has an id, assignment_id.
- I have a assignments table, which has an id, title and other fields.

Each answer belongs to a problem. In the answer table, I can retrieve all the answers to a problem by using the problem_id.

Each problem belongs to an assignment. I can retrieve all the problems of an assignment, using the assignment_id in the problems table.

I need to retrieve the final best score of a student in a problem for an assignment.

Is there a way to achieve this without using multiple queries.

Comment: What do you mean by final best score?

Comment: I think he refers to the student whose score was the best for the assignment.

Comment: A student may have multiple answers for the same problem in an assignment. I would like to get the best score from those attempts. If  two answers by the same person for the same problem have the same score but different time stamp, final best score is the earlier one. i Hope this was clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering these relations:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :problem

class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assignment
  has_many :answers

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :problems # or has_one, whatever

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :problems, through: :answers # You might not have this relation configured
```

You could do:

```
scope = Student.includes(answers: { problems: :assignment })
scope = scope.where(problems: { title: '3x + 2 = 12' })
scope = scope.where(students: { name: 'Johnny' })
scope = scope.where(assignment: { id: my_assignment_id })
scope = scope.select('MAX(score), *') # not sure about this part, depending on your needs
```

Answer (score 0):

To view all students best assignment score for a given assignment/problem this should work:

```
select student_id, problem_id, assignment_id, max(score)  from answers 
join problem on answers.problem_id = problem.id
join assignments on problem.assignment_id = assignments.id
where assignment_id = <your assignment param>
and problem_id = <your problem param>
and answers.id = <your answers id>
group by student_id
```

However you should be able to do away with the assignment_id param assuming a problem is unique to a single assignment.

Comment: Hey, your code retrieve the maximum score irrespective of the solution id. I mean if there are multiple attempts by the same person, it retrieves the maximum score from another solution by that same person.

Comment: @ChrisL, you should update the group by if you're adding fields.